# Prevent negative numbers in computing age

Tags: javascript

How to fix this? To not have a negative output

```
<script>
    $("#bday").change(function(){

    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date($('#bday').val());
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
   return $('#age').val(age);
});
</script>
```

> Output:

[image: This is the output]

Comment: Can you please post your code as text? Thank you!

Comment: So what will be the age in the example you provided? would it be `0` or something else (Like an error message)

Comment: `Math.abs(-2)` = 2 ? if you want 0 thats obvious, just check if `< 0` somewhere

Comment: An alert will pop-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check if the age is possitive, otherwise set it to 0. If age es possitive, when change the date, check if it is bigger than 0 and subtract one. See the comments in the code.

```js
    $("#bday").change(function(){

    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date($('#bday').val());
    var age = 
      today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear() >= 0 
      ? today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear()
      : 0; // Check if 'age' is bigger or equals to 0, otherwise set to 0
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
      if (age > 0) {
        age--; // Subtract a year if 'age' is bigger than 0
      }
    }

    $('#age').val(age);

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="bday"></input>
<input id="age" type="text" disabled></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you allow putting a future date as a birthday then you'll have a negative number. So you can either put a max on your input field to equal today or in your formula instead of age-- put age = 0 if that's the lowest value for age that you want.